# PHP stealth redirect not working

Tags: php, redirect, include

I'vee got this little snippet function to redirect visitors to my pranking page without changing the URL:

```
function april_fools($session_id_string)
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['session_id']) || $_SESSION['session_id'] != $session_id_string)
    {
        $_SESSION['session_id'] = $session_id_string;
        include("./april_fools/" . $date_array[2] . ".php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

What it should do, is that it actually includes the pranking page content and executes it, and then exits the program before continuing (next code is not evaluated). Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work :( It relies on a specific date in year. The April Fool's date and session identificator is driven by this snippet:

```
$date_string = date("d-m-Y");
$date_array = explode("-", $date_string);

$session_id = base64_encode($visitor_ip . '/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . '/' . $date_string)
session_start();
```

And the actual "redirect" is made by calling the previous function:

```
if($date_array[0] == 1 && $date_array[1] == 4)
{
    april_fools($session_id);
}
```

But the function doesn't want to work, so the "redirect" doesn't happen. Any idea on how to get it working please? Best using date driven PHP...

EDIT: Solution was cookies clear. Nothing to do with actual code.

Comment: When I try to access the `./april_fools/2018.php` page, the script itself works. But the "redirect" doesn't. Something is wrong on the main redirecting page, but can't quite tell what. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @rollstuhlfahrer hit it on the nose, I'd do it a bit differently:

```
function april_fools($session_id_string){
  if(date('m') == 4 && date('d') == 1){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['session_id']) || $_SESSION['session_id'] != $session_id_string){
      $_SESSION['session_id'] = $session_id_string;
      include("./april_fools/" . date('Y') . ".php");
      exit();
    } else {
      echo 'Session already exists, Nothing to do..';
    }
  }
}
```

Its a variable scope issue, what you would have known if you enabled `error_reporting()`

Comment: I'm using WAMP on Windows, and `notice` and `error` reporting are enabled bz default. Didn't change default behaviour. Nothing has pop out.

Comment: If reporting was on, the if statement `if(!isset($_SESSION['...` is not true. Because it would have certainly giving you a info message about an undefined variable. Clear your cookies, do a hard refresh on the browser.

Comment: Oh crap :D That was it, the damn cookies :D Now it works, thank you :D So it false redirects to the page (includes that page instead of original one) and reloading the page now actually redirects the user to language preset based on IP geolocation :)

Answer (score 1):

The `$date_array` variable is out of scope in your `april_fools()` function. You need to import it using `global`.

```
function april_fools($session_id_string)
{
    global $date_array;
    if(!isset($_SESSION['session_id']) || $_SESSION['session_id'] != $session_id_string)
    {
        $_SESSION['session_id'] = $session_id_string;
        include("./april_fools/" . $date_array[2] . ".php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

If your calling code is inside another method you need to pass the year (`$date_array[2]`) as a parameter.

Or as [Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol) says, pass it as a parameter to this function regardless of scope.

Comment: Or, better, pass it in as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Well, I edited it so the fuction takes the `$date_array` variable as a second parameter, and it still doesn't work. I mean the function itself doesn't work. It basically skips the entire function and continues after it. Like it doesn't exist. Can send complete page with the included one to look after...

Comment: Haven't checked the condition, but there is nothing else wrong with the code.